# Object.entries Property 'length' is missing in type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

With my code

```
for (const [teamName, teamData] of Object.entries<TeamsData>(data)) {
  ...
}
```

I am getting the error

```
Argument of type 'TeamsData' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: TeamsData; } | ArrayLike<TeamsData>'.

Property 'length' is missing in type 'TeamsData' but required in type 'ArrayLike<TeamsData>'.
```

My `TeamsData` type is

```
export interface TeamsData {
  [key: string]: TeamDataStructure;
}
```

Looking at the interface for Object.entries, I see

```
entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
```

So I feel like it should be matching `{ [s: string]: TeamsData; }` but that is not the case. Instead, it looks like it is matching `ArrayLike<T>`, causing it to require `length`. I can use `any` as the type and the error disappears, but I would like to know how to properly use `Object.entries` in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why that's not working, but the problem seems to be your generic type being explicitly passed in.

As long as `data` is strongly typed as `TeamsData`, then you can let the compiler infer `T` for you.

```
interface TeamsData {
  [key: string]: number;
}
const data: TeamsData = { a:1, b:2 }
for (const [teamName, teamData] of Object.entries(data)) {
  //...
}
```